# How to make a rest get call using jsonp and angularjs for a text/plain response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, jsonp, angularjs-http

I'm trying to do the following rest call using $http.jsonp method

for the following rest api that returns a text plain string like this `0 1 1 1/1 * ? *` I get the response but I get the following error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`

here is my code I'm using angularjs 1.5.7

```
 var url = 'http://www.cronmaker.com/rest/'
                            + 'hourly/at?hour=1&minute=1&every=1';

 $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);


 return $http.jsonp(url, {jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback',  transformResponse: false})
                            .success(function (data) {
                                console.log(data);
                            });
```

but I get the following error

```
{"status":404,"config":{"method":"JSONP","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":false,"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://www.cronmaker.com/rest/hourly/at?hour=1&minute=1&every=1","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"cached":false},"statusText":"error"}
```

Comment: does `http://www.cronmaker.com/rest/` support jsonp requests?

Comment: I guess because the request works I get the response, because I can see in my console this  0 22 9 1/1 * ? * , when I click the error number link that appears in red in my console

Comment: no, it does not support JSONP

Comment: how do you know?? and why I can get the response? if it doesn't support it?

Comment: show the **exact** response text you see in the developer tools

Comment: 0 22 21 1/1 * ? *       I think that the error is because it starts with a zero or something

Comment: well, that isn't JSONP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134136/discussion-between-bill-data23-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: Simple solution - don't use JSONP when the API is REST

Comment: but if I don't use jsonp I get this error 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.cronmaker.com/rest/hourly/at?hour=45&minute=21&every=3. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 420.

and I searched for that error and one of the solutions was using JSONP

Comment: `and one of the solutions was using JSONP` - which would work, if the server supports JSONP ... an API doesn't have to support JSONP, or CORS for that matter, it's up to the owner of the service to decide how a client is able to consume the service - this service simply does not allow any form of requests from a browser - proxy the request using **your** server using server side code